# Render treble and bass staves with vexflow

Tags: javascript, vexflow

I have been following the [vexflow tutorial](https://github.com/0xfe/vexflow/wiki/The-VexFlow-Tutorial) for rendering which gives an example for rendering a single stave. This works fine. I now want to render both the treble and the bass which is not explained in the guide. The simplest way I can think of is to just duplicate the example code to render both.

[image]

This kind of works but if I take an example rendered using another tool you can see my example is missing the { joining both sides as well as the line between the bars. Does vexflow offer some built in functionality to render both staves?

[image: musescore rendered sheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the tests it looks like the way to do this is to use VF.StaveConnector

```
  new VF.StaveConnector(stave, stave2)
      .setType('single')
      .setContext(context)
      .draw();

  new VF.StaveConnector(stave, stave2)
      .setType('brace')
      .setContext(context)
      .draw();
```

This adds the straight line and the curly brace.